# removing create react app default styling

Tags: reactjs

I use create-react-app and wanted to change the background-color of my body tag, but it seems like there is a default styling overwritten them. Where does those styles come from?
I didn't see any style being imported nor is it browser default styling.[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are not using any third party library?

Comment: Im using one third party library, how do I know which style came last? I wanted my style to come last in the list

Comment: you should make that order in `index.js` or `App.js`. It depends whether you are calling them in one or another and order them

Answer (score 0):

Remove below line in App.js

```
import './App.css';
```

And below line in index.js

```
import './index.css';
```

Comment: nope i deleted the import but the style still shows up on chrome dev tool

Comment: Can you post your code snippets? So that we can understand in detail

Answer (score 0):

Check in App.css file or Index.css

Comment: nope i deleted the import but the style still shows up on chrome dev tool

Comment: Open index.html file and check code between "<head></head>" tags.
There should be that style.